# Django, just showing once when I use multiple forms with rich editor

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I am creating comment area and reply to comment area for users. And I using `django-ckeditor` for this but there is a problem. When I add "reply form" just showing once in the page. Not showing other forms. The reply system its works just its not showing ckeditor(Rich editor).

**I am add some photos for better understanding:**
[image]

**second form in same page:**
[image]

**inspect of first form:**
[image]

**my Models:**

```
class UserMessages(models.Model):
     postMessages = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, verbose_name="Message")
     post = models.ForeignKey(
                  UserPosts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Linked Post", null=True)
     username = models.ForeignKey(
                  User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Username", null=True)
     replies = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**my Forms:**

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = UserMessages
    fields = ("postMessages",)

    widgets = {
         "postMessages": forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),

#And I tried this but not works..
class ReplyFormMessage(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = UserMessages
      fields = ("replies",)
```

**my HTML:**

```
    <form method="POST" >
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{form.media}}
         {{ form }}
         <input type="hidden" name="replies_id" value="{{ message.id }}">
         <input type="submit" value="Reply" class="btn btn-default">
     </form>
```

**as for me, ckeditor just using one id for all form in page. So, do you have an idea?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use one id for multiple elements in HTML. The purpose of id is to uniquely identify your HTML tags, you can use classes if you want to generalize the tags.

Secondly, make use of [Django inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) to achieve what you want.